# How to rearrange a string as a matrix?

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, matrix

I have MATLAB R2012b in my system. So Communication System toolbox of R2014b is not available there. I can not assess **de2bi()** function. An alternative **dec2bin()** is available there.

Suppose dec2bin(2,9) = 000000010, which is a string containing 9 digits. Now I like to get 000000010 as a vector of length 9 which I can reshape a matrix of $3 \times3$ to use it for further mathematical calculations. How can I do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just subtract `'0'`  (or `48`, which is ASCII for `'0'`), and then `reshape`. This works because subtracting a number, or even a `char`, from a `char` turns it into a `double` corresponding to its ASCII code.

```
>> reshape(dec2bin(2,9)-'0',3,3)
ans =
     0     0     0
     0     0     1
     0     0     0
```

or

```
>> reshape(dec2bin(2,9)-'0',3,3).'
ans =
     0     0     0
     0     0     0
     0     1     0
```